# jQuery include created children in result

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, scroll

I'm inserting a div, every nth-child and then later, calling the children of the parent but the jQuery inserted elements are not in this new list.  How can I get the inserted elements as well.

Sorry if this makes no sense.

This is probably easier in code so here you go.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    alignMultiGrid(4, 5, 5, 1);
});

/**
 * Aligns a grid of objects
 *
 * @param cols       The number of columns in the grid
 * @param cellWidth  the width of each cell
 * @param cellHeight the height of each cell
 * @param padding    the padding between the cells
 */
function alignGrid( /*string*/ id, /*int*/ cols, /*int*/ cellWidth, /*int*/ cellHeight, /*int*/ padding) {

    var x = 0;
    var y = 0;
    var count = 1;

    jQuery("#" + id).each(function () {
        jQuery(this).css("position", "relative");

        jQuery(this).children("div").each(function () {
            jQuery(this).css("width", cellWidth + "em");
            jQuery(this).css("height", cellHeight + "em");
            jQuery(this).css("position", "absolute");

            jQuery(this).css("left", x + "em");
            jQuery(this).css("top", y + "em");

            if ((count % cols) == 0) {
                x = 0;
                y += cellHeight + padding;
            } else {
                x += cellWidth + padding;
            }

            count++;
        });
    });
}

/* 
 * Variables for handling the dynamic multigrid
 */
var gridcount = 0;
var gridwidth;
var gridheight;
var currentgrid = 0;

/* 
 * Positions the grid to a specific grid index.
 */
function positionGrid( /* int */ gridpos) {
    jQuery("#gridnav" + currentgrid).removeClass("gridnavitemselected");
    currentgrid = gridpos;
    jQuery(".multigrid").each(function () {
        jQuery(this).animate({
            left: "-" + (gridwidth * currentgrid) + "em"
        }, 1500);
    });

    /*
     * Set the next and previous links to be visible as needed
     */
    if (currentgrid == 0) {
        jQuery("#prevcontainer").hide(0);
    } else {
        jQuery("#prevcontainer").show(0);
    }

    if (currentgrid == (gridcount - 1)) {
        jQuery("#nextcontainer").hide(0);
    } else {
        jQuery("#nextcontainer").show(0);
    }

    jQuery("#gridnav" + currentgrid).addClass("gridnavitemselected");

    return false;
}

/* 
 * Goes to the next grid position.  The is move right button
 */
function positionGridNext() {
    if (currentgrid == (gridcount - 1)) {
        return false;
    }

    positionGrid(currentgrid + 1);
    return false;
}

/* 
 * Goes to the previous grid position.  The is move left button
 */
function positionGridPrev() {
    if (currentgrid == 0) {
        return false;
    }

    positionGrid(currentgrid - 1);

    return false;
}

/* 
 * Adds an item to the grid navigation bar
 */
function addNavItem(index) {
    jQuery("#gridnav").append("<div id=\"gridnav" + (index - 1) + "\" class=\"gridnavitem\"><a href=\"#\" " +
        "onclick=\"positionGrid(" + (index - 1) + "); return false;\">" + index + "</a></div>");

    /*
     * The navigation area needs to grow wide enough to hold all the items so we'll
     * dynamically set the position of it based on the number of child nav items.
     */
    jQuery("#gridnavcontainer").css("right", ((jQuery("#gridnav").children().length * 3) + 0.5) + "em");
}

/**
 * Aligns a grid that spans multiple pages with dynamic links for
 * navigation between the pages.
 *
 * @param cols       The number of columns in the grid
 * @param cellWidth  the width of each cell
 * @param cellHeight the height of each cell
 * @param padding    the padding between the cells
 */
function alignMultiGrid( /*int*/ cols, /*int*/ cellWidth, /*int*/ cellHeight, /*int*/ padding) {

    var xoffset = padding;
    var x = xoffset;
    var y = padding;
    var cellcount = 1;
    var rowcount = 1;
    var maxrows = 3;

    gridwidth = (cols * (cellWidth + padding)) + padding;
    gridheight = (maxrows * (cellHeight + padding)) + padding;

    currentgrid = 0;


    var n = $(".cell").length;
    var c = (cols * maxrows);

    if (n > c) {
        jQuery(".cell:nth-child(" + c + "n)").before("<div class=\"next\">NEXT</div>");
    }
    /* 
     * First we add the styles and the navigation components to the main grid container
     */
    jQuery(".maingridcontainer").each(function () {
        jQuery(this).css("position", "relative");
        jQuery(this).css("width", (gridwidth + 5) + "em");
        jQuery(this).css("height", (gridheight + 5) + "em");

        /* 
         * Now we'll add the next and previous links
         */

        jQuery(this).append("<div class=\"nextprev\" id=\"nextcontainer\">" +
            "<a href=\"#\" class=\"next\"> > </a>" +
            "</div>");
        jQuery(this).append("<div class=\"nextprev\" id=\"prevcontainer\">" +
            "<a href=\"#\" class=\"prev\"> < </a>" +
            "</div>");


        /* 
         * And now the previous and next link styling
         */
        jQuery("#prevcontainer").each(function () {
            jQuery(this).css("width", "4em");
            jQuery(this).css("height", "2em");
            jQuery(this).css("position", "absolute");

            jQuery(this).css("top", ((maxrows / 2) * (cellHeight + padding) - 0.5) + "em");
            jQuery(this).css("left", "0em");
        });

        jQuery("#nextcontainer").each(function () {
            jQuery(this).css("width", "4em");
            jQuery(this).css("height", "2em");
            jQuery(this).css("position", "absolute");

            jQuery(this).css("top", ((maxrows / 2) * (cellHeight + padding) - 0.5) + "em");
            jQuery(this).css("left", (gridwidth + 2) + "em");
        });
    });

    /* 
     * Now we style the grid container itself and add the navigation bar
     */
    jQuery(".multigridcontainer").each(function () {
        jQuery(this).css("overflow", "hidden");
        jQuery(this).css("position", "relative");
        jQuery(this).css("left", "2em");
        jQuery(this).css("width", gridwidth + "em");
        jQuery(this).css("height", (gridheight + 5) + "em");

        /* 
         * Add the grid navigation bar
         */

        jQuery(this).append("<div id=\"gridnavcontainer\"><div id=\"gridnav\" class=\"grid\"></div></div>");
        jQuery("#gridnavcontainer").each(function () {
            jQuery(this).css("position", "absolute");
            jQuery(this).css("top", (gridheight + 3) + "em");
        });

    });

    /* 
     * And now we are ready to align the grid.  This is where
     * the magic happens
     */
    jQuery(".multigrid").each(function () {
        jQuery(this).css("position", "relative");
        console.log($(".cell").length);
        jQuery(this).children("div").each(function () {
            jQuery(this).css("width", cellWidth + "em");
            jQuery(this).css("height", cellHeight + "em");
            jQuery(this).css("position", "absolute");

            jQuery(this).css("left", x + "em");
            jQuery(this).css("top", y + "em");

            if ((cellcount % cols) == 0) {
                if ((rowcount % maxrows) == 0) {
                    /* 
                     * This means we have added the maximum number of rows to
                     * this page in the grid and we need to push everything
                     * over to the next grid;
                     */
                    y = padding;
                    xoffset += gridwidth;
                    x = xoffset;
                    gridcount++;
                    addNavItem(gridcount);

                } else {
                    x = xoffset;
                    y += cellHeight + padding;
                }

                rowcount++;
            } else {
                x += cellWidth + padding;
            }
            cellcount++;
        });

        /* 
         * This is a little hacky.  I need to see if I have to add a
         * grid to the grid count for a partial grid at the end.  I could
         * make this code a bit cleaner if JQuery has a do/while construct
         * instead of just a for each
         */
        if ((cellcount - 1) % (maxrows * cols) != 0) {
            gridcount++;
            addNavItem(gridcount);
        }

    });

    /*
     * Now we have to align a simple grid for the navigation controls
     */
    alignGrid("gridnav", 6, 2, 2, 1);

    /* 
     * Add listeners for the next and previous links
     */
    jQuery(".next").click(function () {
        positionGridNext();
        return false;
    });

    jQuery(".prev").click(function () {
        positionGridPrev();
        return false;
    });

    /*
     * The last step is to position the grid to the 0 index so the first
     * control will be properly highlighted
     */
    positionGrid(0);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<main>
    <div class="maingridcontainer">
        <div class="multigridcontainer">
            <div class="multigrid">
                <div class="cell">1</div>
                <div class="cell">2</div>
                <div class="cell">3</div>
                <div class="cell">4</div>
                <div class="cell">5</div>
                <div class="cell">6</div>
                <div class="cell">7</div>
                <div class="cell">8</div>
                <div class="cell">9</div>
                <div class="cell">10</div>
                <div class="cell">11</div>
                <div class="cell">1</div>
                <div class="cell">2</div>
                <div class="cell">3</div>
                <div class="cell">4</div>
                <div class="cell">5</div>
                <div class="cell">6</div>
                <div class="cell">7</div>
                <div class="cell">8</div>
                <div class="cell">9</div>
                <div class="cell">10</div>
                <div class="cell">11</div>
                <div class="cell">1</div>
                <div class="cell">2</div>
                <div class="cell">3</div>
                <div class="cell">4</div>
                <div class="cell">5</div>
                <div class="cell">6</div>
                <div class="cell">7</div>
                <div class="cell">8</div>
                <div class="cell">9</div>
                <div class="cell">10</div>
                <div class="cell">11</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</main>
```

The two main bits of this are the element insertion:

```js
    var n = $(".cell").length;
    var c = (cols * maxrows);

    if (n > c) {
        jQuery(".cell:nth-child(" + c + "n)").before("<div class=\"next\">NEXT</div>");
    }
```

And the calling of children which is ignoring the above.

```js
jQuery(".multigrid").each(function() {
  jQuery(this).css("position", "relative");
  console.log($(".cell").length);
  jQuery(this).children("div").each(function() {
    jQuery(this).css("width", cellWidth + "em");
    jQuery(this).css("height", cellHeight + "em");
    jQuery(this).css("position", "absolute");

    jQuery(this).css("left", x + "em");
    jQuery(this).css("top", y + "em");

    if ((cellcount % cols) == 0) {
      if ((rowcount % maxrows) == 0) {
        /* 
         * This means we have added the maximum number of rows to
         * this page in the grid and we need to push everything
         * over to the next grid;
         */
        y = padding;
        xoffset += gridwidth;
        x = xoffset;
        gridcount++;
        addNavItem(gridcount);

      } else {
        x = xoffset;
        y += cellHeight + padding;
      }

      rowcount++;
    } else {
      x += cellWidth + padding;
    }
    cellcount++;
  });

  /* 
   * This is a little hacky.  I need to see if I have to add a
   * grid to the grid count for a partial grid at the end.  I could
   * make this code a bit cleaner if JQuery has a do/while construct
   * instead of just a for each
   */
  if ((cellcount - 1) % (maxrows * cols) != 0) {
    gridcount++;
    addNavItem(gridcount);
  }

});
```

Comment: @isherwood the code is so you can run it to see, the problem code is at the bottom.

Comment: @CorwinCZ when I get the children it is not including the elements I created every 12th child so when I create the grid the "next" button is correct on the first section then it gets offset by 1. If you run the snippet you will see the error with the layout on the second grid.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very simple fix indeed. Instead of inserting the required "next" div before the 12th item, I inserted it after the 11th instead and all seems to be ok.

Thank you for the very constructive answers.  I can now go about cleaning up the code and help others where they require it. /sarcasm.

```js
    var n = jQuery(".release").length;
    var c = (cols * maxrows);
    
    if (n > c) {
        jQuery(".release:nth-child(" + (c -1) + "n)").after('<div class="next release"> NEXT </div>');
    }
```